# Skipping if statements if don't get results form Database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm using Property Model for filtering data. Passing the filter values from the frontend. If the filter can't find matches results coming from the DB just skip the filter. The data is filtered from the Model and the relations as well.

**Problem:**

I want to skip the if statement if there is no result against the query. The problem is I'm not using get() when getting results from the Model because I want to chain query with relations. And if any IF statement becomes false all the data in the matches variable become empty array because I'm not using get(). I want to skip the if statement which becomes false.

````
  $matches = Property::with(['media', 'address', 'customer'])->where([
            'agency_id' => session('agency_id'),
            'purpose' => $propertyRequirement->purpose,
            'category_id' => $propertyRequirement->category_id,
            'sub_category_id' => $propertyRequirement->sub_category_id,
            'urgency' => $propertyRequirement->urgency
        ])
            ->whereRelation('address', 'city', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->city)
            ->whereBetween('price', [$propertyRequirement->min_price, $propertyRequirement->max_price])
            ->whereBetween('area', [$propertyRequirement->min_area, $propertyRequirement->max_area]);
        $filterCounter = 9;
        if (!empty($propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->location) && $matches->whereRelation('address', 'location', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->location)->count() > 0) {
            $matches->whereRelation('address', 'location', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->location);
            $filterCounter++;
        }
        if ($propertyRequirement->category_id === 1) {
            if (!empty($propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->min_bathrooms) && $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'bathrooms', '>=', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->min_bathrooms)->count() > 0) {
                $matches = $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'bathrooms', '>=', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->min_bathrooms);
                $filterCounter++;
            }
            if (!empty($propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->max_bathrooms) && $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'bathrooms', '<=', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->max_bathrooms)->count() > 0) {
                $matches = $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'bathrooms', '<=', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->max_bathrooms);
                $filterCounter++;
            }
            if (!empty($propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->min_rooms) &&
                $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'rooms', '>=', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->min_rooms)->count() > 0) {
                $matches = $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'rooms', '>=', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->min_rooms);
                $filterCounter++;
            }
            if (!empty($propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->max_rooms) && $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'rooms', '<=', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->max_rooms)->count() > 0) {
                $matches = $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'rooms', '<=', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->max_rooms);
                $filterCounter++;
            }
            if (!empty($propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->parking_space) && $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'parking_space', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->parking_space)->count() > 0) {
                $matches = $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'parking_space', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->parking_space);
                $filterCounter++;
            }
            if (!empty($propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->year_build) && $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'year_build', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->year_build)->count() > 0) {
                $matches = $matches->whereRelation('propertyDetail', 'year_build', $propertyRequirement->propertyRequirementDetail->year_build);
                $filterCounter++;
            }
        }  ```
````

Comment: Can you Use get() only for checking in the if statement and pass the model without get() ?

Comment: yes, this is the right way why didn't I think of it. Thanks But how to skip the relation condition can't use get before relation it will through error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `count()` to get the number of records of your initial query. This will be significantly faster than using `->get()`. The reason why you should use `count()`is, that you don't need all the data that you would query with `get()`. Querying only the # of results is obviously faster than retrieving all data.

The code could look like this:

```php
$matchesCount = $matches->count();
if($matchesCount > 0){
//continue with all other if
}
```